# JavaScript - Replace all duplicate values in array with unique values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript function that splits two equal-length arrays with distinct numbers 0-9 in the same random spot, takes the left part of the first array and the right part of the second one and merges the two parts in a new array:

```
function splitAndMerge(arr1, arr2) {
    let slicingLocation = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); // 6

    let arr1Subarray = arr1.slice(0, slicingLocation);
    let arr2Subarray = arr2.slice(slicingLocation);

    return arr1Subarray.concat(arr2Subarray);
}

let foo = [7, 0, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 9, 1, 8];
let bar = [1, 3, 8, 5, 9, 4, 7, 2, 0, 6];

let newArray = splitAndMerge(foo, bar);

/*
    Slicing at index 6:
    [7, 0, 6, 5, 4, 3, | 2, 9, 1, 8];
    [1, 3, 8, 5, 9, 4, | 7, 2, 0, 6];

    Returns [7, 0, 6, 5, 4, 3, 7, 2, 0, 6];

*/
```

Is there a way to remove all duplicates from `bar` and replace them with new, distinct values (the returned array should look like `[7, 0, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 8, 9]`)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: i dont understand how is this ? `7 should be turned to 1, 0 to 8 and so on`

Comment: It's pretty unclear what the logic is here. Do your initial arrays already contain duplicates or not? Are you saying your initial arrays are always 10 elements long containing all numbers from 0-9 exactly once? Or, what else?

Comment: *equal length*, *left*, *right*, *merge* ...? please add some examples from where you like to go and the result (and the steps between, as well).

Comment: Let me get this straight… you have two lists of numbers from 0-9, contiguous. What you want to end up with is a list of numbers from 0 to 9, without duplicates. Sooo… basically the same as the input, just in a different order. Sooo… what you really want is to *shuffle* (part of) the list?!

Comment: Mihail, are you trying to merge all the numbers in both arrays with the duplicate integers removed?

Answer (score 1):

You could map the merged array by taking a closure over an empty [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) `s` for storing all used values and a variable `i` for the next unused value.

In the mapping, the value is check against the set and if not included, this value is returned. If not check the the set with the next possible value id if used, increment the value until a not used value is found.

Then add the value to the set, to prevent another use of the value and return this value.

```js
var array = [7, 0, 6, 5, 4, 3, 7, 2, 0, 6],
    result = array.map(((s, i) => v => {
        if (!s.has(v)) {
            s.add(v);
            return v;
        }
        while (s.has(i)) ++i;
        s.add(i);
        return i;
    })(new Set, 0));
        
console.log(result.join(' '));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 var selected = Array.from(new Set(newArray.map(c => c)));
```

Comment: don't post code-only answers. Try to explain how your code solves the problem posted by OP.